# How can I increase performance of MySQL when creating and working with a huge database?

Tags: mysql

Firstly: I'm no expert and I'm running Windows. Sorry! :-)

I have about 100 GB of data in txt-files. I want to move part of each line to a list. The list should contain as few duplicates as possible and should be sorted by number of occurences, most frequently encountered parts first. I've picked MySQL as the tool for the job.

Below is what I've come up with so far. It works with small samples, but takes unbelievably long, obviously. I think MySQL may be crashing in the background.

1. Can I make the code below more efficient?
2. Can I configure MySQL itself to be more efficient? It barely uses any hardware. CPU, RAM and I/O are all around 10%.

```
/* Create tables */

CREATE TABLE `raw_data` (
    `whole_line` VARCHAR(765) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs', /* Most lines are much shorter than 765, but some may not be */
    `part_one` VARCHAR(765) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs',
    `part_two` VARCHAR(765) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs',
    UNIQUE INDEX `whole_line` (`whole_line`) USING BTREE /* Unique to get rid of duplicate lines. Not sure if this costs more time now than it saves later. */
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_as_cs'    /* Case sensitivity is required */
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED    /* Is this any good? */
;

CREATE TABLE `sorted_list` (
    `count` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `item` VARCHAR(765) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_as_cs',
    UNIQUE INDEX `item` (`item`)    /* Unique to get rid of duplicate items */
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_as_cs'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
;


/* Import lines */
/* Example line. A few thousand files need to be imported like this. */

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\datafiles\\0.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE `secret_database`.`raw_data` LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (`whole_line`);


/* Split lines */

UPDATE `secret_database`.`raw_data` SET
    `part_one` = IF(
        LOCATE(':', `whole_line`) > 0,
        SUBSTRING(`whole_line`, 1, LOCATE(':', `whole_line`) - 1),
        `whole_line`
    ),
    `part_two` = IF(
        LOCATE(':', `whole_line`) > 0,
        SUBSTRING(`whole_line`, LOCATE(':', `whole_line`) + 1),
        NULL
    );
        
        
/* Move relevant part to new table, count and discard duplicates on the way */

INSERT INTO `secret_database`.`sorted_list` (item)
SELECT `part_two` from `secret_database`.`raw_data` 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1;


/* Sort data */


ALTER TABLE `secret_database`.`sorted_list`
    ORDER BY `count` DESC;

ALTER TABLE `secret_database`.`sorted_list`
    ADD COLUMN `id` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER `item`,    /* The idea is to export this in chunks of n rows later without sorting ever again */
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
    
    
/* Export data */

/* Guess I'll do that with a GUI */
```

Comment: you can male the update direct in the LOAD data, this should be faster

Comment: What is the average length of `whole_line`?  (`AVG(LENGTH(whole_line))`)

Answer (score 0):

Do some timings before depending on `COMPRESSED`, it may actually slow things down.

Instead of having long text strings to test for dups, use some digest.  I suggest `MD5()` for your app.  Better yet stuff that in a `BINARY(16)`:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (..., UNHEX(MD5(".....")), ...)
```

Then dedupping and counting those 16-byte quantities will be more efficient.  Furthermore, there is no 765 limit needed on your "lines".

A 4-byte `INT UNSIGNED` tops out at 4 billion.  Do you really need an 8-bytes `BIGINT`?

As for the collation...  You say `_as_cs`?  That's no much different from `_bin`.  Do you need to do a collated comparison?  Or is a binary comparison good enough?  (My digest suggestion depends on a binary comparison being good enough.)

Answer (score 0):

@nbk:

Good idea. Saves space, at the very least!

---

@Rick James:

I chose COMPRESSED because I was under the impression that I could trade CPU time for storage space this way. I'll definitely do a comparison, as storage space isn't necessarily an issue - space on the SSD, on the other hand, might be, and disk speed is probably more limiting than CPU speed, so I want to keep it on there.

So far, I've only added small chunks of data to the database for testing. The average length of whole_line across the whole set will probably be 30 to 40 characters, but some may be significantly longer. The part_two that I'm extracting is more likely around 15 characters.

Regarding the md5-hashes: So basically you suggest that I create another column in raw_data and sorted_list to store that hash and use it for comparison?
I was expecting the unique index to do all that for me, to be honest.

There are "only" around 4 billion lines total, so you're right, I probably won't need a BIGINT to count the results.

Binary is actually much better, thanks!